# When should the gravedigger claim?

Tags: werewolv.es

E.g. what if he digs up a shifter, or what if he digs up someone important like the seer, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule for claiming. You need to consider what is best for the village before revealing any information. If there are already roles revealed and the lynch looks like it's going in a good direction why would you claim? Take your time and assess whether claiming helps the village or hinders it. I think this goes for any village role.

Always consider if you're giving helpful information to your team. If you reveal that the Protector is dead on D3 are you a) telling evils that they can freely kill and/or b) revealing your role and making yourself a target. 
Sometimes holding back information is more valuable, you can catch an evil in a lie.